# Sweetalert2: open external link in new tab on Yes

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

I implemented this survey pop-up using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/). After 5 pageviews, the pop-up with Yes - No question apears after 3 seconds on page loaded.

The problem is I want the external url to be opened in a new tab / window. I already tried `window.open(survey_url, '_blank');`, but it has issues in IE. User must allow pop-ups and it seems the link is not opened.

Is there any better solution in sweetalert2 context? I mean having a simple button with link or something?

```
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    var survey_delay = 3000; // milliseconds
    var survey_delay_pageviews = 5;
    var survey_title = "This is a title!";
    var survey_text = "Would you be willing to say Yes?";
    var survey_url = "http://google.com";

    if(!localStorage.getItem("survey_answered")) {
      var pageviews = (+localStorage.getItem("page_views") || 0) + 1;
      localStorage.setItem("page_views", pageviews);

      if(pageviews >= survey_delay_pageviews) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          swal({
            title: survey_title,
            text: survey_text,
            type: "success",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
            cancelButtonText: 'No'
          }).then(function(result) {
            localStorage.setItem("survey_answered", "true");
            window.location.replace(survey_url);
          }).catch(function() {
            localStorage.setItem("survey_answered", "true");
          });
        }, survey_delay);
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: have you tried a button link with the attribute `target="_blank"`?

Comment: Maybe it's simple, but I have no idea how to put it. :)

Comment: if by *put it* you mean the attribute in the anchor tag, it's something like this `<a target="_blank" href="new.html">df</a>`

Comment: I know. But where do I put this a href? confirmButtonText: 'Yes << here?'

Comment: I guess, I mean I haven't seen your html but from the question I would say yes

Comment: Should work this way, please make sure do not use mixed content as http vs https `swal({
            title: survey_title,
            text: survey_text,
            type: "success",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: '<a href="https://facebook.com">dfg</a>',
            cancelButtonText: 'No'
          })` working plunker [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/elvY9teJQ3QCwfN4TBuo?p=preview)

Comment: Not a solution: it just replaces my Yes with the external link, but it's a link inside a button... Clicking the rest of button has not the same effect. I also need to set 'localStorage.setItem("survey_answered", "true");' when Yes or No is clicked - the pop-up must not appear after this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by replacing the default button with link button with `_blank` target. Added just before my `}, survey_delay);` line:

```
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("button.swal2-confirm").replaceWith('<a target="_blank" class="swal2-confirm swal2-styled" style="background-color: rgb(48, 133, 214); border-left-color: rgb(48, 133, 214); border-right-color: rgb(48, 133, 214);" href="' + survey_url + '">Yes</a>');
    $("a.swal2-confirm").click(function () {
      localStorage.setItem("survey_answered", "true");
      swal.close()
    })
  }, 400);
```